# Entity Framework Core with Azure CosmosDB is repeatedly initialised

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating an REST API with Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) as my database with Entity Framework Core. I am add the DbContext as a dependency when I configure services like so:

```
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
                options => options.UseCosmos(CosmosDbEndpoint, CosmosDbAuthKey, CosmosDbName, cosmosOptionsAction => cosmosOptionsAction.ConnectionMode(ConnectionMode.Direct)));
```

The DBContext itself is implemented  in the standard way

```
    public class PharmacyExpressContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        protected PharmacyExpressContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public PharmacyExpressContext (DbContextOptions<PharmacyExpressContext> options): base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {...
        }
        
        //DbSets here
        ....
}
```

When I inspect the logs I noticed that each time I call my API, Entity Framework is initialised all over again this is logged:

`2020-09-07T11:28:28.790492961Z: [INFO]        Entity Framework Core 3.1.7 initialized 'MyContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos' with options: ServiceEndPoint=https:[Redacted] Database=[Redacted]`

Suggesting that the connection is not persistent. Then after a couple of requests I will get

`2020-09-07T11:37:49.899167416Z: [INFO]  CosmosException;StatusCode=TooManyRequests;SubStatusCode=3200;ActivityId=176a9a48-9e57-4c17-9135-8ac776406c81;RequestCharge=0;Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 429 Substatus: 3200 Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large. More Request Units may be needed, so no changes were made. Please retry this request later. Learn more: http://aka.ms/cosmosdb-error-429"]}`

I tried increase the RUs on my Database from Azure but that did not help. Other implementations I went through created a client from which CRUD is done but those did not include EF Core.  I am not sure what I am missing.

**Edit**
Not sure if this is relevant but I also creating a partition storage on the same database for storing User State and Conversation State.

```
 var storage = new CosmosDbPartitionedStorage(
                new CosmosDbPartitionedStorageOptions
                {
                    CosmosDbEndpoint = CosmosDbEndpoint, 
                    AuthKey = CosmosDbAuthKey, 
                    DatabaseId = CosmosDbName, 
                    ContainerId = CosmosContainerId, 
                    CompatibilityMode = false, 
                });


            var conversationState = new ConversationState(storage);
            services.AddSingleton(conversationState);

            var userState = new UserState(storage);
            services.AddSingleton(userState);
```

Comment: Add `options.ExecutionStrategy(d => new CosmosExecutionStrategy(d));` in OnConfiguring() to handle 429 requests in CosmosDB. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you... let me try this.

Comment: Could you please check if the database has bee already created?  If it has been created, please remove `Database.EnsureCreated()` as it will try to check the database and create models on every request which is not recommended and will create performance issues.

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT it did not work.

Comment: @JimXu trying that

Comment: @JimXu that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql#throughput. We can  change the default retry count by setting the `RetryOptions` on the `CosmosClientOptions` instance to fix it.

Comment: Ideally, it should not be reinitialized as it is taken care of by the SDK. Can you verify if 429s are coming because of continuous re-initializing?

Comment: Thank you @JimXu increasing my TCP idle time has worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @HarshitaSingh-MSFT

Answer (score 2):

This solution solved the Error 429 problem for me....

```
services.AddDbContext<PharmacyExpressContext>(
   options => options.UseCosmos(
       CosmosDbEndpoint, 
       CosmosDbAuthKey, 
       CosmosDbName,  
       cosmosCLientOptions =>  
           new CosmosClientOptions  
           { 
              IdleTcpConnectionTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(1, 0, 0 , 0)
           }));
```

I still get the `Entity Framework Core 3.1.7 initialized` in my logs but the responses for my API calls are markedly faster and I am no longer getting a too many requests error.

Details on further improving performance are recorded [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql#throughput)